# Prove a summation equals 1

Tags: summation, proof-writing, algorithms

I'm working on an algorithms problem and I've come to the following generalization, but I'm not sure how to prove it.  Could anyone help?

$$
\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^{i}}\ +\ \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\ =\ 1
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^{i}}+ \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\\
=\frac12+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots+\frac1{2^{n-2}}+\frac1{2^{n-1}}+\frac1{2^{n-1}}
$$
Now add the two rightmost terms together, and simplify them, and you get
$$
=\frac12+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots+\frac1{2^{n-3}}+\frac1{2^{n-2}}+\frac1{2^{n-2}} 
$$
And then you can repeat this, adding the two rightmost terms and simplify, all the way until you reach $\frac12+\frac12=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{i}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$, can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Use mathematical induction:

- *Base Case:*

  - When $n=2$ we have $$\frac 1{2^{2-1}}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2-1}\frac 1{2^i}=1$$ which is true as $\tfrac 12+\tfrac 12=1$.
- *Iterative Case:*

  - Suppose for all $n\geq 2$, that $$\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac1{2^{i}}=1$$
  - Now *you need to* derive that $$\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac1{2^{i}}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n} u_1\cdot r^{i-1} = \frac{u_1\big(r^n-1\big)}{r-1}$$

Apply this to $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^i}$$

and see what you get.